# Connect 3 iMac 21" Screens together?

Tags: imac, display

What's the best solution to connect 3 iMac screens together so they're all usable as one large screen.

I currently have 2 iMac's connected together via a single thunderbolt to thunderbolt cable (Which works fine, mouse goes between the 2 screens etc).

However my 3 iMacs only have 1 thunderbolt port each so there's no spare port to connect the 3rd screen.
Similar image to the ports available on the 3 iMacs:
[image: https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/p5qamiXqPusrQlfG.medium]

Comment: What a lovely image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need is splitter so you can connect 2 displays to your Thunderbolt port so you can use the both iMac with Target Display Mode.

It's the only way to use these iMacs as screens.

Comment: I've had a look for a thunderbolt splitter but they don't really seem to exist?

Answer (score 1):

a work round is to use usb adaptor like display link for a third display via DVI not ideal but useable for work but not good for video or gaming third screen won't run quartz composer screen savers etc (as for using iMac as third display not sure if usb to DVI to thunderbolt would work)